# Getting volume_id of non-root device in Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

How do I filter out (assuming the use of when) ebs volumes that are not 'dev/sda1'?

For example, the playbook is:

```
- name:                     List Volumes
  ec2_vol:
    region:                 "{{ aws_vars.region }}"
    instance:               "{{ ec2.instances[0].instance_id }}"
    state:                  list
  register:                 volumes
  when:                     volumes.device_name != '/dev/sda1'
- debug:                    msg="{{ volumes.volumes | map(attribute='id') | list }}"
```

This does not work.

The var for volumes is something like:

```
[
        {
            "attachment_set": {
                "attach_time": "2018-05-28T11:17:56.000Z",
                "deleteOnTermination": "false",
                "device": "xvdf",
                "instance_id": "i-00ac0585d1d4974aa",
                "status": "attached"
            },
            "create_time": "2017-07-18T14:54:28.969Z",
            "encrypted": false,
            "id": "vol-0506598d250ffe3d3",
            "iops": 450,
            "size": 150,
            "snapshot_id": "snap-0ce6832b64cfa093d",
            "status": "in-use",
            "tags": {
                "Site Desktop 1": "IIS",
                "project-group": "DEV"
            },
            "type": "gp2",
            "zone": "eu-central-1b"
        }
```

Comment: for those not working with ec2, can you provide the `volumes` variable, or if all the information is in the `{{ volumes.volumes | map(attribute='id') | list }}`, that output instead?

Comment: I've added the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The when statement is executed **before** the task (it decides whether the task should be run or not), so it can't be used to filter the results.

Using the [set_fact module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) you can edit the results from a task and save them in a new variable. I used that in combination with the j[son query filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter):

```
  - name:                     List Volumes
    ec2_vol:
      region:                 "eu-west-1"
      instance:               "i-0f7gd2b0090924864"
      state:                  list
    register:                 volumes
  - set_fact: filtered="{{ volumes.volumes | json_query('[?attachment_set.device!=`/dev/sda1`]') }}"
  - debug:                    msg="{{ filtered }}"
```